# MySQL and JSP Database connectivity with Glassfish server 4

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, glassfish

Here is my code.

```
    **insert.html**
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Donate Blood !</title>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            </head>
            <body>
                <form action="store.jsp" method="POST">
                    Name: <input type="text" name="nam"><br>
                    Rollno: <input type="text" name="rno"><br>
                    Blood Group: <input type="text" name="grp"><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add me !">
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>

**Store.jsp**
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%
            String name = request.getParameter("nam");
            String roll = request.getParameter("rno");
            String group = request.getParameter("grp");

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blood","root","");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into blood(Name,Rollno,BloodGroup) values('+name+','+roll+','+group+')");
        %>
```

My database..
[image]

I am running this code in netbeans 8.0. I got the error log as
[image]

It shows that data is too long for blood group but i just given 'A+' in that textbox. Whats going wrong. As I am new to JSP please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the data you trying to insert into `BloodGroup` column is large, then you have specified size when creating table..

Comment: check my answer to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using PreparedStatement instead to avoid String concatenation mistakes.

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("insert into blood(Name,Rollno,BloodGroup) values(?,?,?)");
st.setString(1, name);
st.setString(2, roll);
st.setString(3, group);
st.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

The query must be executed as 
int i=st.executeUpdate(**"insert into blood(Name,Rollno,BloodGroup) values(' "+name+" ',' "+roll+" ',' "+group+" ')"**);

Answer (score 0):

The Exception:

`com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long..`

is says, the data you trying to insert into `BloodGroup` column is larger then you have specified column data size when creating table.

So fix is:

change size of `BloodGroup` column like:

```
ALTER TABLE blood MODIFY BloodGroup varchar(some value more than 5);
```